# Selenium Webdriver will not execute next step after opening browser and going to System Admin

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, java-test-fixtures

Hi guys I have been trying to automate our Web browser, I have the Main class where I call all my classes that I create as soon as I run the Test, the open_Browser will run and when its done it will just stop there but I have called the other function in side of the main aswell.

theres code of my Main:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        openWeb();
        testCase001();

    }


//This function called the OpenSystemAdmin class.
    public static void openWeb() {
        OpenSystemAdmin open = new OpenSystemAdmin();
        open.openWeb();
        open.pressAdminLoginButton();

    }
//This function called the TestCaseWithValidDetails class.
public static void testCase001() {
    TestCaseWithValidDetails testCase = new TestCaseWithValidDetails();
    testCase.testCaseWithValidDetails1();
}
```

```
package System_Admin_Tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import static System_Admin_Tests.ScreenShot_Function.screenShot;
import static System_Admin_Tests.ScreenShot_Function.screenShotNames;
import static org.openqa.selenium.By.id;

public class TestCaseWithValidDetails {

    public static WebDriver driver;


//TestCase ID : LogIn_001

//Test Description : Verify that the logIn function works with the right details.
    public static void testCaseWithValidDetails1() {

        //username
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(id("edmail"));
        username.sendKeys("email");
        //Password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(id("email"));
        password.sendKeys("password");
        /*
        Enter Button
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
           screenShot(driver, "Screenshots_LogIn.Passes //" + screenShotNames());
         } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        */


        OpenSystemAdmin.enterButton();

        /*
         try {
             screenShot(driver, "Screenshots_LogIn.Passes //" + screenShotNames());
          } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
         System.out.println("Login in test passed");
        */

    }

}
```

this is my OpenSystemAdmin code:

```
public class OpenSystemAdmin {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void openWeb() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("driverChromeDriver",
                    ".mvn/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://mrflutter.000webhostapp.com/");



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




//This function is there to press the System Admin button on the home screen.
    public static void pressAdminLoginButton() {
        WebElement pressSystemAdmin = driver.findElement(By.linkText("SYSTEM ADMIN"));
        pressSystemAdmin.click();
    }








//Some Added functions:

//EnterButton
public static void enterButton() {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();
}
```

I was expecting it open Web Browser and the click on System Admin then enter the username and password then click enter to signing.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you post `OpenSystemAdmin` source? Or tell me how are you passing `driver` to `TestCaseWithValidDetails`  class?

Comment: here is OpenSystemAdmin

Comment: this is there error I am getting;   Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "System_Admin_Tests.TestCaseWithValidDetails.driver" is null

Comment: You're not using the same driver between the two classes, share the same variable / make it common / move to a common class to solve the problem.